# average of nth line from mutiple files into one average master file

Tags: data, math

I have 3 files which contain 8 lines of numerical values and text. I'm trying to take the average of each rows across all three files and print a new file with those averages.
The three example files are below, all with the same name format of testfile1.1, testfile1.2, testfile1.3

**Testfile1.1**

```
1
2048
8
5
5
4
9
Lat:1
```

**Testfile1.2**

```
1
2048
10
7
7
4
9
Lat:1
```

**Testfile1.3**

```
1
2048
3
6
3
4
6
Lat:7
```

I'd like the output file to look like the following (after the averages are taken)

**Averagefile1**

```
1
2048
7
6
5
4
8
Lat:3
```

Hopefully this makes sense what I'm trying to do!

I've tried using different combinations of awk, sed which worked fine for 3-4 lines of data but my actual data has 2000+ lines across 40+ file names

EDIT: So I was able understand how to control the sig figs I wanted printed out and how to edit the regex to match the floating decimals better.

(Please let me know if I should put this as a different question and delete this one!).

My actual data has lots of other lines that have text along with values that I would like to take average of. I tried to create additional strings but then got even more confused. within my real files, on certain lines I would like to different commands such as print text from lines, take averages on the actual data, lines to copy text and average of data and take average of dates and times.

Below are copies of 2 files (with comments on each line what I would like to have done to them).

Tofu1.1

```
ABCDEFGH #print text into output file (same on both files)
1     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
2048  # Take average of values across all the files in this line
8     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
5     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
5     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
4     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
9.5   # Take average of values across all the files in this line
1     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
90.00  # Check and make sure value in this line across print if same
Sprite # check and see if text is same across all values and print if same
cats10   # check and see if text is same across all values and print if same
07/02/20 # See below for explantion on next 3 lines
08:32
08:32
290.000000 # average across all 3 files on this line
10.750000 # average across all 3 files on this line
SCANS23   # output should be SCANS "average of values"
INT_TIME57500 # output should be INT_TIME with sum of all values
SITE northpole   #Check if all lines are same if so print line
LONGITUDE -147.850037  # Output should be LONGITUDE%f
LATITUDE 64.859375     # Output should be LONGITUDE%f
```

Line 13 is the date the data is from, line 14 is the time if started and the time it ended. Probably using someway date to decimal command.. is there a way to take the average of the date? If one data was taken on 07/02/20 and the other from 07/02/18 can the output be 07/02/19? the average of the times would be taken into account too.

Tofu1.2

```
ABCDEFGH #print text into output file (same on both files)
1     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
2048  # Take average of values across all the files in this line
10    # Take average of values across all the files in this line
7     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
7     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
4     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
8   # Take average of values across all the files in this line
1     # Take average of values across all the files in this line
90.00  # Check and make sure value in this line across print if same
Sprite # check and see if text is same across all values and print if same
cats10   # check and see if text is same across all values and print if same
07/02/20 # See below for explanation on next 3 lines
08:32
08:32
290.000000 # average across all 3 files on this line
10.750000 # average across all 3 files on this line
SCANS23   # output should be SCANS "average of values"
INT_TIME57500 # output should be INT_TIME with sum of all values
SITE northpole   #Check if all lines are same if so print line
LONGITUDE -147.850037  # Output should be LONGITUDE%f
LATITUDE 64.859375     # Output should be LONGITUDE%f
```

I tired an attempt at a script to try to include multiple string start values but got really messy real fast.

```
awk -F: '
  FNR==1     { c++ };
  /^LATITUDE/    { a[FNR] += $6 };
  /^SCANS/    { a[FNR] += $2 };
  /^[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/ { a[FNR] += $1 };

  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf (i==22 ? "LATITUDE%f": i==18 ? "SCANS%2.3f": "%f") "\n", a[i] / c
    }
  }' tofu1.* > askforhelp
```

Which gave me

```
$ more askforhelp

90.000000
LATITUDE0.000000
290.000000
10.750000
SCANS0.000
1.000000
2048.000000
6.333333
4.666667
5.000000
4.000000
7.833333
2.666667
```

I also tried adding multiple strings of text at once and got really confused when I got absolutely no output from this attempt.

```
awk -F: '
  FNR==1     { c++ };
  /^LATITUDE/    { a[FNR] += $6 };
  /^LONGITUDE/    { a[FNR] += $5 };
  /^SITE/    { a[FNR] += $4 };
  /^INT_TIME/    { a[FNR] += $3 };
  /^SCANS/    { a[FNR] += $2 };
  /^[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/ { a[FNR] += $1 };

  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf (i==22 ? "LATITUDE%f": 
              i==21 ? "LONGITUDE%2.3f": 
              i==20 ? "SITE%2.3f": 
              i==19 ? "INT_TIME%2.3f": 
              i==18 ? "SCANS%2.3f": "%f") "\n", a[i] / c 
    }
  }' /home/lmdjeu/test/test1.* > /home/lmdjeu/test/askforhelp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F: '
  FNR==1     { c++ };
  /^Lat:/    { a[FNR] += $2 };
  /^[0-9]+$/ { a[FNR] += $1 };

  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf (i==8 ? "Lat:%i" : "%i") "\n", a[i] / c
    }
  }' Testfile1.* > Averagefile1

$ cat Averagefile1
1
2048
7
6
5
4
8
Lat:3
```

This uses variable `c` to count the number of files it had read in. `c` is incremented whenever the first line of a file (`FNR==1`) is read.   `FNR` is awk's automatically set input record (line number) counter, it is reset for each input file read.

It also uses an array `a` to store the cumulative sums of each line of input - `FNR` is used as the index of the array.  If the line contains only digits, the first (and only field) on that line is added to the array element for that line.  If it starts with the string `Lat:`,  then the second field is added instead.

Once all the input files have been read and processed, the END block is executed.  This iterates over the array, printing the sums in each element divided by the count of files.  All but the 8th line is printed as just an integer.

For the 8th line, the integer is prefixed by the string `Lat:`. The script uses awk's ternary operator for this: `condition ? result_if_true : result_if_false`

Comment: fantastic I got it working with the example files! now I just have to convert it to run on my actual files which I think I can edit thanks to your explanation with the code!

My actual data doesn't have such pretty numbers as the example files I showed. Is there a way to print out additional significant figures in the average1.1 file? I'm hoping to get it to read 6 places after the decimal!

Comment: @LucasDjeu In `printf` `%i` stands for integer as format. Have a read of the [manuals](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html) and pick your desired output format, e,g. `%f.6` for floating point numbers with variable length before and 6 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: As @FelixJN mentions, use `%f.6` for 6-digit floating point output.  You'll also need to modify the regex so that it matches floating point numbers, and maybe + or - signs too.   e.g. instead of `^[0-9]+$`, something more like `^[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$`, and the regex gets even more complicated if you need to match exponential notation.  For that, you'd need `[+-]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)`.

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers) for details and more alternatives.

Comment: @cas or @ FelixJN
I got a little stuck when trying to add more strings to the output with my real data (the syntax got really messy real fast. If you're able to provide some feedback on my edit that be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not really worth using the ternary operator when you've got that many cases - it was only worth doing because there was only one case that needed to be handled slightly differently to all the rest.   In awk, I'd probably create an array of printf format strings (with the same index numbers as the data) in a `BEGIN {}` block, and iterate over one of the arrays, so that each data element got printed with its associated format string. e.g. `for (i in a) { printf fmt[i], a[i] / c}`.    I'd be more inclined to use perl, though - it has nice features for working with arrays and array slices.

Comment: also, your `Tofu1.*` "actual" data files are **very** different to your Testfile1.* sample files.  Different enough that they require a new question, as they require a different approach to processing them.

Comment: Thanks Cas! I'll be sure to create a new question and delete this one since it's kind of going to be a duplicate.